# Create multiple tables using single .sql script file

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created multiple table in oracle xe 11g database and i have saved the script for each table in different .sql file. But i need to create all tables at once using single .sql file.
I tried to run below script but it is creating only once table at once.

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_DETAILS_TB 
(
  CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL 
, ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE ADDRESS_DETAILS_TB 
(
  ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL 
, ADDRESS_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL 
);
```

Comment: SQL statements need to be terminated with a `;`

Comment: i tried by adding the semicolon, but if i run the script using command prompt then only it is creating two table for me.

Comment: Your script only contains two `CREATE TABLE` statements. Why do you think it should create more?

Comment: its miscommunication ;). i meant only through command prompt i am able to create two table, but if i try the same thing in sql developer it is creating only one table at once.

Comment: In SQL Developer you need to use "Run Script" (not "Run Statement") if I'm not mistaken. But I am confused: you are clearly using Oracle and SQL Developer yet you accepted an answer that is for SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio (which is **not** able to talk to an Oracle database)

Comment: i tried with run script button also. And i accepted the answer for Sql Server since my colleague has tested that.

Comment: How can your colleague test an Oracle script using SQL Server?

Comment: he is working on sql server :P he tested the script to create multiple table same way we do in oracle.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to separate the create table scripts with `/` or end the command with `;`, Try like this,

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_DETAILS_TB ( CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL , ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL )
/
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS_DETAILS_TB ( ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL , ADDRESS_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL )
/
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_DETAILS_TB ( CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL , ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE ADDRESS_DETAILS_TB ( ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL , ADDRESS_ID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL );
```

Comment: It would be really nice and consistent with the other statements if [tag:sql] could interpret `create table (...), table2 (...), table3 (...)` as it interprets the `VALUES` clause of `INSERT` statement, for instance.

Answer (score -6):

I ran this script by changing the VARCHAR2 to NVARCHAR in SQL Server and found there are 2 tables created in the database in the name of

- ACCOUNT_DETAILS_TB1
- ADDRESS_DETAILS_TB2

Here is the screenshot of my database and the 2 tables created are rounded.

[image: Screen shot of my database]

Comment: And how does a screenshot for a SQL Server tool answer a question that is clearly marked as Oracle?